# I was writing code for database through mongoose but I am getting this error on the terminal mongoose.connection.on error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error every time I start the app.....error is in the screenshots. Please let me know how to fix this up.Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii57h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDoOc.png)

Comment: It looks like the mongoose package is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You got error because Mongoose.connection is not yet exists when you try to access it. You need either use callback as

```
const Mongoose=require("mongoose").connect(config.dbURL,(error)=>{
     if (!error) {
         Moongose.connection.on("error",(error)=>{...your code here ..});
     }
})
```

or use Promise

```
const Mongoose=require("mongoose").connect(config.dbURL)
    .then(()=>{
         Moongose.connection.on("error",(error)=>{...your code here ..});
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use some variables/identifiers to store the connection as explained in the Mongoose documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html).

`console.log` your `config` and check whether they are being properly fetched.

The community also helps better if you provide more details and use code snippets instead of screenshots.

Next, check if your Database URL starts with `mongodb://`.

And then, you have a spelling error on `line 19` where you define schema `charUser` but are trying to model `chatUser` on `line 27`.

Try putting `Mongoose.promise = Promise;` just after you import mongoose.

Also, I'd suggest you to use the following style:

1. Create `db.js` which will export the database connection for you.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

const options = {
  poolSize: 25,
  socketTimeoutMS: 0,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30,
  user: 'MONGODB_USER',
  pass: 'MONGODB_PASS',
  auth: {
    authdb: 'MONGODB_AUTH_DB',
  },
};

const dbname = 'db_name_goes_here';
const host = 'db_server_URI_goes_here';
const port = port_number_goes_here || 27017;
const uri = `mongodb://${host}:${port}/${dbname}`; // a template string

const db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, options);

module.exports = db;
```

2. Use the connection in the Model file in this manner:

```
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');
const db = require('./db.js');
const chatUser = new Schema({
    profileID: String,
    fullName: String,
    profilePic: String
});
const userModel = db.model('chatUser', chatUser);
module.exports = { userModel };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 // Connection URL
 const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';  
// Database Name
const dbName = 'test';
// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
assert.equal(null, err);
console.log("Connected successfully to server");
const db = client.db(dbName);
});
```